# how come $C^{1}_{0}$ is not complete under norm $||.||_{1,2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

why  the space $C^{1}_{0}$ is not complete  under the norm $||.||_{1,2}$? by some counter example

$||u||1,2=(\int_{\Omega} (|\nabla u |^2+|u|^2))^{1/2}$

Comment: Ask 10 mathematicians and you'll get 5 different answers what $C_0^1$ and what $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ is. You are the one asking for help; is it too much then to at least provide some minimal information about your problem? Normally such minimal information should also include your previous thoughts and attempts

Comment: @Bananach sorry

Answer (score 1):

My intuition on why it is not complete: it is already complete under the usual norm $\|f\|_{\sup}+\|\nabla f\|_{\sup}$. The Sobolev norm too measures both $u$ and $\nabla u$ in a similar fashion (the version you wrote down is equivalent to $\|f\|_{L^2}+\|\nabla f\|_{L^2}$) but with supremum norms replaced by $L^2$ norms, which makes the Sobolev norm strictly weaker. It would be surprising if the space was still complete with a strictly weaker norm (there is a theorem that says that this is indeed impossible: The open mapping theorem).

Also note that the above reduces, on an intuitive level, your question to the question why the continuous functions are closed under $\| f \|_{\sup}$ but are not closed under the $L^2$ norm. For this you will easily find the counterexample of a step function which is the $L^2$ limit of continuous functions.  This non-rigorous thinking will lead you to a rigorous solution: Integrate the step function, and you will have a counterexample for your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Take $C^1_0= C^1_0((-1,1))$ and look at $u(x)=  |x-1|$. It's not difficult to see that $||u||_{1,2}$ is finite and that there is a sequence $u_n \in C^1_0((-1,1))$ which converges to $u$ in that norm.

(Define $u_n(x)=u(x)$ if $|x|>\frac{1}{n}$ and $=-\frac{1}{2} n x^2 +b_n $ for $|x|\le \frac{1}{n}$ with $b_n$ chosen so that this is $C^1$ near $\pm \frac{1}{n}$. This is $C^1_0$ and (after a short caluculation and ignoring the origin as a set of measure $0$) $$ |\nabla u-\nabla u_n|^2=\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|1-nx|^2$$ is $=\left. (x-nx^2+\frac{n^2}{3}x^3)\right|_{-1/n}^{1/n} = O(\frac{1}{n})$